# I made a script that detects if there is white space surrounding an image and automatically removes it, sometimes, it still leaves some of it

Tags: javascript, crop

The code is a simple image cropper that allows the user to select an image file, crop the image to remove any surrounding white space, and then download the resulting cropped image.

My problem is that sometimes the code leaves a little bit of white space around some images and i don't have any idea on why it does that.

Here is my code:

```
      // Add an event listener to the file input field to process the selected file
      document
        .getElementById("fileInput")
        .addEventListener("change", function () {
          // Get the file object
          var file = this.files[0];

          // Create a FileReader object
          var reader = new FileReader();

          // Add an event listener to the FileReader object to process the file when it's loaded
          reader.addEventListener("load", function () {
            // Create an image object and set its src to the data URL of the file
            var img = new Image();
            img.src = this.result;

            // Wait for the image to load
            img.onload = function () {
              // Get the width and height of the image
              var width = img.naturalWidth;
              var height = img.naturalHeight;

              // Create a canvas element and draw the image onto it
              var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
              canvas.width = width;
              canvas.height = height;
              var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
              ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

              // Get the image data of the canvas
              var imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, width, height);
              var data = imageData.data;

              // Iterate through the image data and determine the edges of the non-white pixels
              var top = height;
              var bottom = 0;
              var left = width;
              var right = 0;
              for (var y = 0; y < height; y++) {
                for (var x = 0; x < width; x++) {
                  var index = (y * width + x) * 4;
                  if (
                    data[index] !== 255 ||
                    data[index + 1] !== 255 ||
                    data[index + 2] !== 255
                  ) {
                    // This pixel is not white, so update the edges if necessary
                    top = Math.min(top, y);
                    bottom = Math.max(bottom, y);
                    left = Math.min(left, x);
                    right = Math.max(right, x);
                  }
                }
              }

              // Calculate the dimensions of the cropped image
              var croppedWidth = right - left;
              var croppedHeight = bottom - top;

              // Create a second canvas element and draw the cropped image onto it
              var croppedCanvas = document.createElement("canvas");
              croppedCanvas.width = croppedWidth;
              croppedCanvas.height = croppedHeight;
              var croppedCtx = croppedCanvas.getContext("2d");
              croppedCtx.drawImage(
                img,
                left,
                top,
                croppedWidth,
                croppedHeight,
                0,
                0,
                croppedWidth,
                croppedHeight
              );

              // Get the data URL of the cropped image and set it as the href of the download link
              var downloadLink = document.getElementById("downloadLink");
              downloadLink.href = croppedCanvas.toDataURL();

              // Set the download attribute of the link to the file name of the original image
              downloadLink.download = file.name;

              // Set the src of the cropped image element to the data URL of the cropped image
              var croppedImage = document.getElementById("croppedImage");
              croppedImage.src = croppedCanvas.toDataURL();
            };
          });

          // Read the file as a data URL
          reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        });
```

I tried adding a little bit of white tolerance but it seems not to fix the problem.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: We need a working example, hence we need the image that is failing and a [snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356678/stack-overflow-run-code-snippet) with the running code. I'm pretty sure that the image is not full white. Just check manually the color of the edges that seem white and are left without cropping. The code seems correct. If the image is a JPEG, compression will make it not full white, but to have artifacts. As you said, you need white tolerance (just like Photoshop with the magic selection tool) and sometimes this tolerance has to be really high [+]

Comment: [+] as is not the same to have a white pixel, that the human eye feeling that a zone is white, but it may have gray pixels inside that the human eye is missing, so is a bit difficult to create an algorithm that detects what the human eye feels that is white versus what is actually white. You need to compare surrounding pixels and so on.

Comment: @JorgeFuentesGonzález what you said is exactly what is happening with my code, i think i might need more white tolerance i'll see what i can do, thank you.